# RecyclerView add item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

By saving a new Image I want to add it to the RecyclerView.
My Problem is that it is not working with that:

```
 profilAdapterImages.notifyItemInserted(list.size() -1);
 profilAdapterImages.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

I don't want to reload the activity, I would like to have the animation.

This is in onActivityResult when I saved the image in the Database.

```
savePicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    encodeBase64 base64 = new encodeBase64();

    Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("username",USERNAME);
    map.put("row","IMAGELINK");
    map.put("data",base64.encodeImage(bitmap, 
    Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,70));
    map.put("mode","2");
    updateData updateData = new updateData(Profil.this);
    updateData.sendDataUpdate(map, new VolleyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onUserExists(String[] result) {
          if(result[0].equals("ok")){
              previewPicture.dismiss();
              Toast.makeText(Profil.this, "Dein Bild wurde gespeichert!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                profilAdapterImages.notifyItemInserted(list.size() -1);
                profilAdapterImages.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void OnSuccess() {

    }

    @Override
    public void OnError(String ErrorMessage) {

    }
});

progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

The Adapter:

```
public class ProfilAdapterImages extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProfilAdapterImages.ViewHolder>{

List<getterImages> list;
Context context;
ImageSettingsCallback imageSettingsCallback;

public ProfilAdapterImages(List<getterImages> list, Context context, ImageSettingsCallback imageSettingsCallback) {
    this.list = list;
    this.context = context;
    this.imageSettingsCallback = imageSettingsCallback;
}

@Override
public ProfilAdapterImages.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.image_slider,parent,false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ProfilAdapterImages.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    getterImages getterImages = list.get(position);

    Picasso.with(context).load(getterImages.getImageURL()).resize(200,200).centerCrop().into(holder.blurImageView, new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            holder.blurImageView.setBlur(20);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError() {

        }
    });

    Picasso.with(context).load(getterImages.getImageURL()).placeholder(R.drawable.preload).resize(200,200).centerCrop().into(holder.imageView, new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            RoundedBitmapDrawable roundedBitmapDrawable = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(context.getResources(),drawableToBitmap(holder.imageView.getDrawable()));
            roundedBitmapDrawable.setCircular(true);
            holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(roundedBitmapDrawable);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError() {

        }
    });

    holder.imageButtonImageSettings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            imageSettingsCallback.onImageSettings(position);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    BlurImageView blurImageView;
    ImageView imageView;
    ImageButton imageButtonImageSettings;


    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        blurImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewSlider);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageButtonImageSettings = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonImageSettings);
    }
}

public static Bitmap drawableToBitmap (Drawable drawable) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;

    if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
        BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) drawable;
        if(bitmapDrawable.getBitmap() != null) {
            return bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
        }
    }

    if(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() <= 0 || drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() <= 0) {
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1, 1, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); // Single color bitmap will be created of 1x1 pixel
    } else {
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    }

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    drawable.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}
}
```

What do I wrong?

I load the pictures with Picasso from my Webspace.
In the Database they are saved in one row seperated with a semicolon.

Comment: profilAdapterImages.notifyDataSetChanged(); will invalidate whole list view, so profilAdapterImages.notifyItemInserted(list.size() -1); doesn't make sense. Here we can't see your adapter and other important code like, where do you get bitmap...

Comment: Thanks for your comment Viktor. I added the Adapter.

Comment: You notify that the item is inserted, but it doesn't appear you actually add the item to your list.

Comment: How should I do that? Load the new data from the database and put it in a new list?

Answer (score 0):

notify `profilAdapterImages.notifyDataSetChanged();` doesn't do anything unless the **adapter** and **RecyclerView** refresh itself, which means you either have To scroll to make the change happen

or you have another option:

I would swap the Adapter with itself.

For example, If you set your adapter originally like this:

```
ProfilAdapterImages  mAdapter = new ProfilAdapterImages(list, context, imageSettingsCallback);
recyclerview.setAdapter(mAdapter);
recyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true);
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

You have your Adapter, Just Swap the Adapter with Itself like this:

```
savePicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
      ProfilAdapterImages  nAdapter  = new ProfilAdapterImages(list, context, imageSettingsCallback);
      recyclerview.setAdapter(nAdapter);
      recyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true);
      nAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

      ....
    }
```

Comment: You do not need notifyDataSetChanged after a setAdapter

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

I loaded the data new, cleared the list, and added
it new and notifyDataSetChanged and smoothScrollToPosition.